# select data from php sql tables

Tags: php

I have a error with my login script. The connection is successful but it does not display a success message when the login is successful. Still displays my dbconn file message.

**Any ideas on how to make this work?**

dbconn code

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'peerwise';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

$link = mysqli_init();
$dbconn = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $db, $port);

if (!$dbconn){
    echo "Not connected to database";
}else{
    echo "Successfully connected";
}

?>
```

login code

```
<?php
    include_once("includes/dbconn.php");        

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";       

    $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());                        
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if ($data['username'] == $username && $data['password'] == $password) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "errr";
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: _"Still displays my dbconn file message"_ - What message?

Comment: yep will add the security but i was trying to just get a login first. The message being displayed is "Successfully connected".

Comment: _"but i was trying to just get a login first"_ - That's doing things backwards. Why would you spend time writing and debugging code that you need to rewrite when your done? Do it correctly from scratch instead and you don't need to refactor it.

Comment: because you added echo in else condition and it will always echo message on your page.

Comment: but the echo on the login page "success" is never printed

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can remove the `mysqli_init()` and just go with `mysqli_ connect()` in this case, since you're not testing the result of init or pass any flags to Mysql before connecting.

Comment: better to follow this for db connection and don't use echo after successful connection: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: i still have the same issue. the login php is not echoing the statements within that

Comment: For security sake, i hope the `Users` table is empty in production

Comment: not for production. Practicing PHP

Comment: Does this line also not work - echo "errr"; ?

Comment: nope and echo success does not either

Answer (score 1):

Your using the wrong connection object. Rather than variable **$dbconn** use **$link** instead in your query calls, so no mysql error will halt execution of your script, from **or die(mysqli_error());**

Replace with this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: In login code:    $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());      to        $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Your using the wrong connection link. Rather than $dbconn use $link instead in your query calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login-form-1">
            <form id="login" class="text-left" method="POST" action="loginprocess.php">
                <div class="main-login-form">
                    <div class="login-group" id="login">
                        <div class="form-group">  
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="login-button" onclick="loginFieldCheck()">Login</button>
                </div>
                <p id="emptyMessage">Username or Password is incorrect</p>

                <p class="create-account"><a class="create-account" onclick="register()">Create a account</a></p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_connect` for connection:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$dbconn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db,$port);


if (!$dbconn){
    echo "Not connected to database";
}else{
    echo "Successfully connected";
}

?>
```

Comment: Change port to 8889